# How to get original file size from GPG-encrypted file?

Tags: linux, gnupg

I have a large file encrypted with GPG and I also have the key to decrypt it. How can I get the size (in bytes) of the original unencrypted file, without actually decrypting the whole encrypted file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default gpg uses compression, but if no compression was used then the original file is almost the same size as the .gpg file (a test with `-z0` only added about 80 bytes).

Normally gpg doesn't tell you the size of the decrypted file, but since you've got the passphrase you can start to decrypt the file using some extra verbosity (with at least two `-v`'s, or `-vv`), only throw away the decrypted data by writing it to `/dev/null` with `--output`, all together your command might look like

```
gpg -vv --output /dev/null bigfile.gpg
```

After decryption starts you'll see the info you want in the line that starts with "raw data", as in:

```
        raw data: 298000 bytes
```

It should take only a few seconds for the verbose data to get printed to the terminal (stderr), so just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> afterwards to cancel the rest of the decryption.

Answer (score -2):

I urge you to ask the person to give you the checksum file.

This is a common practice used when distributing software.

- create a checksum file
- sign the checksum file
- distribute both the software and the checksum file

If the checksum verification passes, then recipients know that your software has not been modified.

If the checksum file is signed by you, then recipients know that it is the correct checksum file for the distributed software.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. My file isn't even a software.

Comment: Is the checksum file supposed to be for the decrypted data file, and is it supposed to contain it's original size?